# How do I assess correlation between ordinal responses to multiple survey questions

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, survey, ordinal-data

I have survey data on whether ~500 respondents would accept a hypothetical medical procedure in variable circumstances. Responses are graded 1 - definitely yes ; 2 - probably yes ; 3 - probably no ; 4 - definitely no. Respondents have been presented with the same question in six different situations.

I wish to test for correlation between responses: specifically I anticipate that individuals who would accept the procedure in one situation would be more likely to accept the procedure in the other situations and vice versa.

I think that I could use Spearman's Rank-Order to compare two of the groups, but how can I assess for correlation across all six?

Thanks very much